# List value issue

Tags: python, list, variables, printing

Firstly, sorry for the poor title. I'm not sure how to describe this problem:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

aa = 0
bb = 0
cc= 0

list = [[1, a] ,[2, b] ,[3 ,c]]
print(list)

secondList = [aa, bb, cc]

x = -1
for item in list:
    x=x+1
    if list[x][1] == a:
        print(aa, "aa")
        secondList[x] = secondList[x] + 1
        print(aa , "aa")
        print(x, "x")
        print(secondList[x], "SecondList[x]")
        secondList = [aa, bb, cc]
        print(secondList)
```

I expect:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
0 aa
1 aa
0 x
1 SecondList[x]
[1, 0, 0]
```

but instead I get:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
0 aa
0 aa
0 x
1 SecondList[x]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Why is the value of aa not changing when I print it or secondList, but is when I print secondList[x]?

Answer (score 1):

Becuase they are independents, one thing is the variable aa and one other is the first element of your second list.

Doing:

```
secondList = [aa, bb, cc]
```

doesn't make dependence

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of the first position in the list "secondList" has nothing to do with changing the value of the variable "aa".

When you create secondList you use the values of the variables aa,bb,cc in a new memory address that is different from the addresses used by aa,bb,cc.

Answer (score 0):

The line

`secondList = [aa, bb, cc]`

copies `aa, bb, cc` by *value* into `secondList`. Although integers in Python are objects, user defined ones of which are copied by *reference*, they are *primitive* types underneath, so a shallow copy is enough to create a new integer with the same value.

Therefore `aa` does NOT refer to `secondList[0]`. So `secondList[x] = secondList[x] + 1` does NOT update `aa`.

EDIT: as proof of what I mean, try the following:

```
x = 1
y = x
x = 2
print(y)
```

It is implied that you would think this prints "2", but it instead prints "1". This shows that integers, and *all other primitive types*, are copied by value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94365/discussion-on-answer-by-willywonka-dailyblah-list-value-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Integers are immutable, so when you do `secondList[x] + 1` you are creating a new integer object with the value `1` and sticking that in your list, rather than modifying the immutable `0` being stored in `aa`.